Are there $a,b$ such that the infinite series of reciprocals of primes of the form $a+bk, gcd(a,b)=1$ is convergent?
My motivation to this question is the divergence of the infinite series of all primes $2$ and primes of the form $2k+1$, so I want to know if there exist $a,b$ such that the primes of the form $a+bk, gcd(a,b)=1$  is convergent. (Of course Dirichlet's theorem guarantees existence of infinitely many primes of this form )

I don't know enough to post an answer, but I think the primes in those arithmetic progressions are asymptotically equally distributed among the congruence classes so all the sums of reciprocals will diverge.

Not following.  Since the list of primes in that progression is infinite, of course you can choose a subset of them such that the sum of the reciprocals taken from that subset is convergent.  Just make sure that the $n^{th}$ element in that subset is greater than $n^2$, say.  Is that what you are asking?

Wikipedia's article on Dirichlet's theorem (states that: "Stronger forms of Dirichlet's theorem state that for any such arithmetic progression, the sum of the reciprocals of the prime numbers in the progression diverges" - so I think the answer to your question is "no", i. e. all such sequences diverge.

@lulu Thanks for ideas, but no this is not what I want, because this will arbitrary subset of primes that need not be progression for example taking
${2,5,11,17,29,... }$ which are greater than ${1,2,4,9,16,25,...$, so by comparison test summation of their reciprocals is convergent, but these don't form arithmetic progression.

Not following.  There can't be an infinite progression consisting entirely of primes.  If the first one was $p$ and the period was $d$ then $p+p\times d$ is not prime.  Anyway, nothing in your post suggests that you wanted the subset to be a progression.

I'm assuming that you mean sequences consisting of all the primes in an arithmetic sequence, for example if you have $a = 3, b = 8$.  Then this "strong Dirichlet" says that the series  $1/3 + 1/11 + 1/19 + 1/43 + 1/59 + 1/67 + 1/83 + 1/107 + \cdots$, where the denominators are the primes of form $8k + 3$, is divergent.

@lulu I mean it is subset of progression of the form $a+bk$

@MichaelLugo Yes something like your example, so they are all divergent even though in each form we are excluding many primes, I mean when excluding free squares from harmonic series it converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Please edit your post for clarity.  As it stands, your question is far from clear.  If all you wanted is a subset of the primes of the form $a+bk$, then my first comment shows you what to do.  It's a very simple argument!  Nothing specific to primes, it works for any infinite subset of the natural numbers.

@lulu My question is talking about all the primes of specific form $a+bk$, for example $8k+3$ as in MichaelLugo comment above

Ok, but the sum of the reciprocals of those diverges.   Your post asks about an "infinite subset" of those primes.  Again, please edit your post for clarity.

@lulu I have edited it, Is it clear now? And I am grateful for your advice of making the question  clearer

No.  You still speak of an infinite subset of the list of the primes in that progression and now you don't even mention the sum of the reciprocals.  Again:  my guess is that you mean to ask "is there an infinite set of primes ${p_k}$ in that given progression such that $\sum \frac 1{p_k}$ converges?"  And, again, that follows immediately from the argument I gave (once you know that Dirichlet guarantees infinitely many primes in the progression).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The sum over $\frac{1}{p}$ for infinitely many primes of the form $p\equiv a\bmod b$ diverges, because we have the following, for $a$ and $b$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{\substack{p \equiv a \bmod b \\ p \leq x}} \frac{1}{p} &= \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} d\lfloor \pi_{a,b}(t) \rfloor \\
&= \frac{\pi_{a,b}(t)}{t} \bigg|_1^x + \int_1^x \frac{\pi_{a,b}(t)}{t^2} dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\varphi(b)} \frac{1}{\log x} + \int_1^x \frac{1}{\varphi(b)}\frac{1}{t \log t} dt + O \left( \int_1^x \frac{e^{-c \sqrt{\log t}}}{t}dt \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\varphi(b)} \log \log x + O(1).
\end{align}$$
Here $\pi_{a,b}(x)$ denotes the number of primes up to $x$ that are congruent to $a \bmod b$.

I have found interesting the question. Your affirmative answer is much stronger than Euler's theorem on $\dfrac 1p$
